# Can't exec "glibtoolize": No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, homebrew, command-line

I have a shell script `autogen.sh`, I run it under my project directory in terminal:

```
./autogen.sh
```

I get error:

> Can't exec "glibtoolize": No such file or directory at
>   /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm
>   line 345,  line 4.

Then, seems it can not find glibtoolize, so I tried to figure out where is my glibtoolize. Eventually, I find it is in this path:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/bin/glibtoolize
```

Then, I get stuck, how to solve my problem after I found my glibtoolize?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you already have `libtool` installed via `brew` but it is not linked so the required symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` are still missing. To create them,

```
brew link libtool
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into multiple problem while downloading protobuf. Try

```
brew install libtool
```

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem after adding glibtoolize to the PATH variable it worked.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: This just sets the path, which doesn't link anything.

Comment: Ja, that is true, I changed my answer. In any case this solved my problem, as brew somehow did not make glibtoolize globally available.